# how to return mysql query and an object

Tags: mysql, node.js

I need to return the MySQL query and an object from a function

when I try this code it works

```
const executeScript = (id, usersData, result) => {
  db.query(`UPDATE users SET ? WHERE users_id=${id}`, usersData, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            result(null, err);
        } else {
            result(null, res);
        }
    });
};

executeScript(update(id, usersData), (err, results) => {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        res.json(results);
    });
```

I need to use this format because of these functions is in different files

```
const update = (id, usersData) => {
    return `UPDATE users SET ? WHERE users_id=${id}`, usersData;
};


const executeScript = (query, result) => {
db.query(query, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        result(null, err);
    } else {
        result(null, res);
    }
});
};

executeScript(update(id, usersData), (err, results) => {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        res.json(results);
    });
```

Comment: You can't expand a '?' into an expression.

Comment: may I know how could this be corrected? or what I'm going to try is impossible